# Cannot deserialize LocalDate from Integer in Avro format by Apicurio deserializer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro

My setup:

1. Strimzi Kafka
2. Apicurio Schema Registry
3. Use Avro format to produce and consume

All works fine with simple types (`String`, `long`)  until I try to use `LocalDate`.

Here is my Avro schema in Apicurio:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "AvroMessageBean",
  "namespace" : "com.company",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "message",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "time",
    "type" : "long"
  }, {        
    "name": "weekEndingDate",
    "type": {
        "type": "int",
        "logicalType": "date"
    }
  }]
}
```

In my consumer I receive `GenericRecord` with `value` like this:

```
{"message": "Hello (0)!", "time": 1615449454839, "weekEndingDate": 18697}
```

The relevant consumer code fragment is like this:

```
import io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.AbstractKafkaSerDe;
import io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.AvroKafkaDeserializer;
...
// set deserializer
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
props.putIfAbsent(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, AvroKafkaDeserializer.class.getName());
props.putIfAbsent(AbstractKafkaSerDe.REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG_PARAM, REGISTRY_URL);

KafkaConsumer<Long, AvroMessageBean> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

...
// consume
while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<Long, AvroMessageBean> records = consumer.poll(Duration.of(1L, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
    for (ConsumerRecord<Long, AvroMessageBean> record : records) {
        GenericRecord gRec = record.value();
        AvroMessageBean aMsg = (AvroMessageBean) SpecificData.get().deepCopy(AvroMessageBean.SCHEMA$, gRec);
        System.out.println("Consumed a message: " + aMsg.getMessage() + " @ " + new Date(aMsg.getTime()));
    }
    consumer.commitSync();
}
```

The exception at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.time.LocalDate
    at com.ibm.AvroMessageBean.put(AvroMessageBean.java:131)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.setField(GenericData.java:818)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.setField(GenericData.java:841)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.deepCopyRaw(GenericData.java:1286)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.deepCopy(GenericData.java:1223)
    at com.ibm.AvroMessageBeanConsumer.main(AvroMessageBeanConsumer.java:75)
```

This is the content of `AvroMessageBean.SCHEMA$`:

```
{"type":"record","name":"AvroMessageBean","namespace":"com.company","fields":[{"name":"message","type":"string"},{"name":"time","type":"long"},{"name":"weekEndingDate","type":{"type":"int","logicalType":"date"}}]}
```

Wondering why the `logicalType` is ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, as I found a solution thanks to Apicirio developer (Fabian Martinez)

There is a special property for the consumer which handles deserialization directly to the business object, instead of `GenericRecord`. And also consumer recognizing `logicalType` and properly handling it:

```
import io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.avro.AvroDatumProvider;
...
// Deserialize directly to AvroMessageBean
props.putIfAbsent(AvroDatumProvider.REGISTRY_USE_SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG_PARAM, true);
...
...
AvroMessageBean aMsg = record.value();
// AvroMessageBean aMsg = (AvroMessageBean) SpecificData.get().deepCopy(AvroMessageBean.SCHEMA$, gRec);
System.out.println("Consumed a message: " + aMsg.getMessage() + " @ " + new Date(aMsg.getTime()) + " @ " + aMsg.getWeekEndingDate());
```